# What php-apc hit value mean?

Tags: php, caching, apc

In apc.php, I can see :

```
Request Rate (hits, misses) 1110 cache requests/second
```

What this value mean ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always look at the [source of apc.php](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/caching/apc.git;a=blob_plain;f=apc.php;hb=HEAD):  the code line responsible for that output is

```
Request Rate (hits, misses)</td><td>$req_rate cache requests/second
```

and `$req_rate` is defined as

```
$req_rate = sprintf("%.2f",($cache['num_hits']+$cache['num_misses'])/($time-$cache['start_time']));
```

where $cache is the output of [apc_cache_info()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php).

So, in plain english it's the average of the sum of cache hits and misses (hence, the total request rate) per second over the time the cache has been running.